# OpenCL - copying a struct from global to local memory

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

I have a struct Primitive, which has the following definition:

```
typedef struct Primitive {
    float m[12];
    float invm[12];
    enum PrimitiveType type;
    int rayDensity;
    float util1;             
    float util2;                
} Primitive;
```

I pass an array of these structs to my kernel in a constant memory buffer:

```
__constant Primitive *objects;
```

As part of an optimization exercise I want to look at loading the structs into local memory, so my kernel has code to the likes of this:

```
__kernel void test(int n_objects, __constant Primitives *objects) {
    local Primitive pFrom, pTo;

    for(int i = 0; i < n_objects; i++) {
        pFrom = objects[i]; 
    }

}
```

When I run this I get a compilation error saying :

```
ptxas application ptx input, line 42; error: State space mismatch between instruction and address in instruction 'ld'
```

As an experiment I have tried first copying the struct to a private variable and then to the local variable as follows :

```
__kernel void test(int n_objects, __constant Primitives *objects) {
    Primitive pF, Pt;
    local Primitive pFrom, pTo;

    for(int i = 0; i < n_objects; i++) {
        pF = objects[i]
        pFrom = pF; 
    }

}
```

Which now compiles and runs however it seems like the object is not deeply copied into the local variable pFrom.

Please note that my code samples are purely samples and I have removed everything for the sake of brevity. Also my code works fine when I use the primitive structs directly from the constant global memory.

Does anyone know what I am missing here, surely its some basic fundamental to deep copying or OpenCL address spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the [async_work_group_copy function](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/async_work_group_copy.html). You can wait for this async operation to finish using the [wait_group_events](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/wait_group_events.html) function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The async_work_group_copy function with wait_group_events is the answer, I am surprised this did not come up in any of my searches. Strangely enough however loading the struct into local memory instead of using constant is increasing the run time. Maybe a broadcast from constant memory is faster than I thought

Comment: Are you interleaving the copy of the next item(s) and the processing? That makes a HUGE difference.

Comment: I have reshuffled the order of operations to call async_work_group_copy earlier and on all elements then do some work before I have the wait barrier and use the objects. This ahas given a small (around 4%) run time reduction. However this method will not scale well with an increasing number of structs as I it will run out of local memory.

Comment: for copying a normal float array, from global to local, I experimented with replacing a simple per-thread copy with async_work_group_copy, and async_work_group_copy was significantly, and surprisingly slower.  I'm fairly sure my code was correct, though you never know.  Maybe this is related to the slow performance you're seeing using async_work_group_copy?  Maybe you can copy your structs by casting it to an array of floats/ints briefly? (Note, I was using an nvidia k520 device)